# How to make a specific symbol

Tags: symbols

How do I make the attached symbol in LaTeX so that I can use it in normal sentences?
[image: FollowingImage]

Comment: What do you mean by *normal sentences*? In TeX you simply type in math mode `$K^C_{F_n}$` or some variant, depending if you want upright shape.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question is a bit ambiguous, but here goes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\KFC{K\scalerel*{\setstackgap{S}{2pt}\Shortstack[l]{C \vphantom{F}%
  \smash{$\mathrm{F}_{\!\mathrm{n}}$}}}{K}}
\begin{document}
Finger lickin' good \KFC.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And I feared that you would post something with `stackengine` already... phew.... wait, it is `stackengine` .... ;-)

Comment: `stackengine` is like the US Marines: it can be your best friend...or your worst nightmare!

Comment: I think there are much more other packages that should be titled `worst nightmare` rather than `stackengine` ....

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `assoccnt` ?

Comment: '@DavidCarlisle: For example, yes ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can always make command for a specific operation like `$K^C_{F_n}$` by using `\newcommand{\command}{operation}`, for 
example:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \newcommand{\kcfn}{$K^C_{F_n}$}
    \begin{document}
    symbol \kcfn
    \end{document}
```

Output: symbol `$K^C_{F_n}$`

You can change the name of the command as you like and also put different specifications as you need like bold or italic, font size etc.

Comment: You're using super/subscripts, that's not really putting the C and F_{n} aside of the letter K, but I agree that the question is unclear